How can fix the remainning characters counter in js
I will create a javascript remaining character counter for an HTML textarea. But my code is not working. How can I fix this.


$(document).ready(function(){

  var length = 0;
  var maximumCharacters = 160;

  $('#description').keyup(function(){
    length = this.value.length;

    if(length > maximumCharacters){

      return false;

    } else if (length > 0){

      $("#remaining-characters").html("Remaining characters: " + (maximumCharacters-length));

    } else {

      $("#remaining-characters").html("Remaining characters: " + maximumCharacters);

    }
  })
})
<div class="row mb-3">
        <label for="description" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label label">Description</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <textarea class="form-control form textarea" id="description" name="description" maxlength="160"></textarea><span id="remaining-characters"></span>
        </div>
      </div>




I wouldn't use keyup event, use input event ... then pasting for example will work too - rather than having the maximumCharacters variable, use the input.maxLength - therefore you don't have to change the value in two places if you decide to change 160 to some other number

What is "not working" here? There is no error; even if the code quality is bad, it worked. Unless you're talking about "$ is not defined" because there is no link to jquery in the stack snippet

Issue in your code: The remaining character count wasn't initialized on page load, and the counter only updated after typing, even though maxlength was set.
What I added: I initialized the remaining characters count to 160 on page load and used .text() to update the count dynamically as the user types, ensuring it reflects the remaining characters accurately.


$(document).ready(function() {
    var maximumCharacters = 160;

    // Initialize the remaining characters when the page loads
    $("#remaining-characters").text("Remaining characters: " + maximumCharacters);

    $('#description').keyup(function() {
        var length = this.value.length;

        // Update the remaining characters
        if (length <= maximumCharacters) {
            $("#remaining-characters").text("Remaining characters: " + (maximumCharacters - length));
        }
    });
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row mb-3">
    <label for="description" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label label">Description</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <textarea class="form-control form textarea" id="description" name="description" maxlength="160"></textarea>
        <span id="remaining-characters"></span>
    </div>
</div>



